# Is there any reason why .NET binary formatter will call GetObjectData multiple times?

Tags: .net, serialization

We are using Binary formatter for serializing object graphs where same object might be referenced by multiple paths. However during Serialization, a specific object's GetObjectData is called numerous times. When tried using a test sample using simpler object, it gets called exactly once independent of the number of times it occurs in the object graph. Is there any reason why the same object will be visited multiple times and .GetObject data might called on the Serializable object during Serialization? When this happens, deserialization seems to fail with FixUp errors.

Comment: Can you show us your code? Are you serializing just one object graph (i.e. calling `Serialize()` just once)? What are “FixUp errors”?

Comment: Apologize that code base is pretty huge to share. Its not one object that is being serialized but a hashtable which will have other objects and the object type in question might be referenced from multiple paths. Exception thrown during deserialization is, "System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: The object with ID 91 was referenced in a fixup but does not exist."

Comment: I'm not asking you to share your whole codebase. But could you share a piece of code that we can use to replicate the problem?

Comment: hi SVick, i am been trying to reproduce with a simpler code, but it always works in sample code! Will post as soon as i find a use case for it. Checked if any transparent proxy or a custom comparer was used for the type that is causing problem, but none found.

Comment: hi SVick, found the problem. It was a bug in .NET. When there are cyclic references and surrogates are used, during deserialization, a problem might happen. Fix is to wrap the inner serialization surrogate with the FormatterServices.GetSurrogateForCyclicalReference( ). It appears to work now, though i will try more use cases to rule out any other issues. Hope that helps somebody and will save time.

Comment: Then you should should post your resolution as an answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Found the problem and resolution. It was a bug in .NET. When there are cyclic references and surrogates are used, during deserialization, a problem might happen. Fix is to wrap the inner serialization surrogate with the FormatterServices.GetSurrogateForCyclicalReference( ). It appears to work now, though i will try more use cases to rule out any other issues. Hope that helps somebody and will save time